# Nodejs v4.4.4 does not install in windows

Tags: node.js, windows

I am trying to install nodejs from [NodeJS](https://nodejs.org/en/) but everytime I run the installer, it rolls back the action and does not install nodejs. I have tried a lot of solutions on the internet but nothing seems to work

1) deleting the TEMP Folder

2) disablin startup services and restart

3) using chocolatey to install

4) installing through command prompt

Below is the log file:-
[installlog](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8czgBw4JQfOMy04cTJhdUc0WWM/view?usp=sharing)
[image]

Comment: Try turning off anti-virus? Why are you using chocately instead of the node installer?

Comment: so you downloaded the 4.4.4 LTS installer, right clicked the installer, clicked "unblock" to make it safe to execute, and then you ran it, and that did not work? That sounds like a software issue, not a programming issue (so you want to ask this on superuser.com, not stackoverflow.com), but also something you might want to ask over on the [official Node issue tracker](https://github.com/nodejs/node)?

Comment: Ya i downloaded the LTS installer, right clicked clicked install. I dont see a unblock option. added the image. Tried installing an older version and it workedv0.10.29. will ask the same on superuser.com.Thanks